# Parse error in existing project

Tags: ios, parse-platform, unrecognized-selector

I see this error when I try to initialize parse with app key and client key.

```
2015-10-08 13:29:56.484 My wish List[7892:4257341] -[ParseManager initWithApplicationId:clientKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe86ac35ef0
2015-10-08 13:29:56.491 My wish List[7892:4257341] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ParseManager initWithApplicationId:clientKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe86ac35ef0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001045bef65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104038deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001045c758d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104514f7a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104514b28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   My wish List                        0x00000001026c7d5f +[Parse setApplicationId:clientKey:] + 212
    6   My wish List                        0x000000010266d07d -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 109
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001049624ca -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 272
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000104963670 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3415
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000104969e15 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1755
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000104966ff0 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    11  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010c7847ac -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    12  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010c784b1a -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001044eb0a1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001044e0fcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001044e0483 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001044dfe98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010496698d -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010496b676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  My wish List                        0x000000010266d30f main + 111
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000105f0292d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```